# Image move when vertical scroll mouse

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel

How can I make an image move smoothly when scrolling mouse wheel up and down like in [this website](http://inuhasa.jp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply reading through the source of the page on the website you linked do, I found that they use an extension of jQuery for easing elements around the page smoothly: https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing

Answer (score 0):

That depends on mouse scroll event,first control mouse event and then join your iamge gallery with mouse scroll,its very simple just a logic